# Trouble including data in package

Tags: r, github, package

I've created my first package, hosted on [github](https://github.com/adsteen/Lloyd.et.al.Cell.abundance.metaanalysis). I'm trying to include three data frames in the package. Per the [Writing R Extensions guide](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages), I saved each data frame as a separate `.RData` file in the `data` subdirectory. However, I can't seem to access the data when I load the package.

When I install the package from a clean R session using

```
require(devtools)
install_github("Lloyd.et.al.Cell.abundance.metaanalysis", "adsteen")
```

the package functions, documentation, and vignette seem to load correctly. Better yet,

```
data(package="Lloyd.et.al.Cell.abundance.metaanalysis")
```

shows the three data frames that are encoded as `.RData` files, named `all_data`, `corrected_seds`, and `corrected_sw`.

The problem is, I can' seem to actually access the data. I have `LazyData: true` at line 21 in the [DESCRIPTION file](https://github.com/adsteen/Lloyd.et.al.Cell.abundance.metaanalysis/blob/master/DESCRIPTION),  so I would expect `head(all_data)` to show the data frame, but it returns an error, `obect 'all_data' not found`. I can't seem to find a way to use `load()` to load the data.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: True using: `LazyData: TRUE` and I think `data(all_data)` is what you'd use to load it if its not lazy loaded.

Comment: Side note - there is no @Description parameter in roxygen

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the package and restarting R?  It seems to work for me...

Comment: @Dason I confirmed as well. (PS longest package name ever)

Comment: Take a (small) package that works from CRAN, and look closely. I often mock up by following working examples.  Also, if something with your `data/` directory is wrong, `R CMD check` would tell. Did you run run it and look for warnings / errors?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Did not, b/c I'm pretty sure that there are other problems with the package that `R CMD check` would flag, but I guess that's not a good reason.

Comment: @DrewSteen: I would heed the warnings and diagnostics. They are there for a reason. The Ostrich algorithm does not help you.

Comment: Soon to be `fortunes::fortune(circa 318)`.